# Physical backspace button mapped to <Del>

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

In insert mode I want <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the characters to the left of my cursor but it's acting just like <kbd>Del</kbd> and removing characters under my cursor.  I saw somewhere I can use `ctrl-k` then a key to see what VIM thinks that key is.  For <kbd>Backspace</kbd> it's returning `<Del>` and for <kbd>Del</kbd> it's returning `<kDel>`.  How can I get my <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key to map to `<BS>` like it should be?  In bash <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is operating normally without me making any special changes.
In PuTTY <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is set to `^?` not `ctrl-h`.

EDIT: I tested vim with the `ctrl-h` backspace setting and vim started working properly.. However I would prefer to leave that PuTTY setting alone unless someone can convince me switching to `ctrl-h` is what I should do, I don't know much about why there are different key codes for backspace and maybe I'd be less hesitant to switch the default PuTTY setting if I knew more.

Comment: What OS are you on? What terminal do you experience this problem in? Do you have `nocompatible` set? What does `:se bs` output?

Comment: you can configure putty to send `^h` instead of `^?`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt switching that makes vim works, read my edit though.

@DJMcMayhem nocompatible is not set, `:se bs` outputs `backspace 2`


I found this http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html
and if I run `stty erase ^?` the issue is fixed without changing PuTTY's settings.  Is this approach considered bad or is it ok if this is the change I make?

Comment: You should change PUTTYs settings, I believe it's the only way. Also, this is unrelated to your question, but you should *definitely* `:set nocompatible` IMO vim is really a terrible editor until you change that setting.

Comment: @ItsComcastic ctrl-h is the traditional key for backspace. So i would go with it. However, I have never encountered the problem in Putty, it has always worked correctly for me and I am using Putty extensively on many machines

Comment: @DJMcMayhem You do realize that it automatically gets turned off when a `vimrc` is detected, right? There's literally no reason to turn it off in your `vimrc`. `:h 'compatible'`

Comment: @tumbler41 Yes, I do realize that. But OP said that nocompatible is *not* set, so they still should set it somehow.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I was unaware that `nocompatible` is automatically set with a `.vimrc` I do have a vimrc so I guess it is set to `nocompatible`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt According to the PuTTY [documentation.](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-backspace)  `If you do have the choice, we recommend configuring PuTTY to generate Control-? and configuring the server to expect it, because that allows applications such as emacs to use Control-H for help.`

Comment: @ItsComcastic Who needs Emacs? ;)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt its not about emacs, it's about needing `ctrl-h` to work properly if I accidentally stumble into emacs so I can figure out how to leave.

Comment: @ItsComcastic the correct keycode for backspace is ctrl-h period. If you use a different keycode, you cannot expect it to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through comments I came to the conclusion that this isn't an issue with vim that I can fix with `.vimrc`  The server is expecting <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to be `ctrl-h` while PuTTY is set to `ctrl-?` by default.

After reading the information [here](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-backspace), particularly this: `If you do have the choice, we recommend configuring PuTTY to generate Control-? and configuring the server to expect it, because that allows applications such as emacs to use Control-H for help.` I decided to change what the server is expecting instead of modifying PuTTy settings. (But the PuTTY setting could be changed instead)

To get the server to expect <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to be `ctrl-?` use the command `stty erase ^?` I added this to my `.profile` to have it automatically get set when I remote into the machine.